# How do I do i change data in some of the fields on my webpage?

Tags: css, html, webshop

I want to create a webshop, And I don't want to create multiple html pages for all the things I want to sell. I just want to update specific fields in my html code. E.g the product name, image, price, description.These would change if I choose another product . How can I do this ?

Comment: You're essentially asking "How do I build a web application?"  That's just far too broad to be meaningfully answered here.  Pick any server-side language and database and start with some introductory tutorials.  For example, if you want to use PHP and MySQL, then you would start with a Google search for "PHP MySQL tutorials".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just get the product list from database through an ajax call to your service , then show it in a repeater . depends on the technology you want to use .
for example if you use angularJs , you can use a div with ng-repeat . if you want to use pure javascript you can render a table in a loop and ...